# how to call a function of the model to a controller, both in nested resources in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 resources, both are implemented by nested resources. The route is as follows: `/students/:id/monitorings/inscribir`

I need to invoke from the monitoring controller the function of the model that is in `students`.

PD: Monitorings has no model, since it does not have a database, since it is an action on the `students` resource

The code of the students model function is the following:

```
def self.calc_credits(id_student)
    credits = 0
    notes = Note.where(student_id: id_student)
    notes.each do |v|
        credits = credits + v.subject.creditos
    end
    return credits
end
```

The code of the monitoring controller is the following:

```
def inscribir
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    @groups = Group.all
    encontrado = false
    @mensaje = ""

    @groups.each do |s|
        if s.subject_id == params[:codigo_materia] and s.student_id = nil
            encontrado = true
        end
    end
    if !encontrado
        @mensaje = "No se ha encontrado ninguna materia disponible"
    end
    creditos = calc_credits(params[:student_id])
    puts creditos
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your monitoring controller, Replace your this line 
`creditos = calc_credits(params[:student_id])` with 
`creditos = @student.calc_credits`

And in your students model, change your calc_credits method to:

```
def self.calc_credits
    credits = 0
    notes = Note.where(student_id: self.id)
    notes.each do |v|
        credits = credits + v.subject.creditos
    end
    return credits
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm if I understood you you are trying to access **student** model method inside **monitoring** controller and **inscribir** action?
If so then you should first get value for student instance like you are doing here.

```
@student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
```

the next thing is to call that method like:

```
@student.thatmethod
```

here you should check if that method inside **student** model **public**? If its is below **private** line in controller then it wont be accessible to this place.